# Kafka Stream ProcessorContext has null ProcessorRecordContext

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using Kafka Streams 2.3.0 to subscribe to a topic with 60 partitions. I am using a custom processor and I see that the init is being invoked multiple times after a return from the internal KafkaConsumer poll where the ProcessorContext.ProcessorRecordContext is null.

As specified in the samples, the custom process stores this context.

Then when the process method is called, we are using this context which results in an error since the record context is null. Before the process method call, the correct record context is created by the caller ProcessorContext implementation, and it forwards the call to the custom processor, but the context held by the custom processor is not set.

What might be the reason for the init method passing in a ProcessContext where the record context is not set?

Thanks for any pointers.

Here is part of the code that I am using.

```
// Topology snippet
props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.RECEIVE_BUFFER_CONFIG, 64 * 1024);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, 1024 * 1024);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, RoundRobinAssignor.class.getName());
props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bservers);
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.ByteArray().getClass().getName());
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.ByteArray().getClass().getName());
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "mygroupId");

Topology builder = new Topology();
builder.addSource(SOURCE_NAME, topic).addProcessor("FilterAndPublish", () -> _processor, SOURCE_NAME);

streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, props);
streams.start();
```

Here is the Processor snippet

```
class CustProcessor extends AbstractProcessor<byte[], byte[]> {
    private EventFilter _filter = new EventFilter();

    @Autowired
    private Publisher _publisher;

    @Override
    public void process(byte[] key, byte[] value) {

        try {
            long offset = context().offset();
            Event evt = _filter.filter(key, value, offset);
            if (evt != null) {
                _publisher.index(evt);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO
        }
    }
```

**Note** that the same code works for the topic with a single partition.

Comment: Could you please add sample code u tried as well

Comment: Actually the issue is with my code - the same processor is being used by each StreamTask that is created for each partition since I did not instantiate a new processor while setting up the topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you add your `Processor`:

```java
addProcessor("FilterAndPublish", () -> _processor, SOURCE_NAME)
```

The second argument is a `Supplier` and a supplier need to return a new object/instance each time it's called. However, your code return the same object on each call, thus breaking the contract of the "supplier pattern" and this results in the exception you get.

You need to change your code to:

```java
addProcessor("FilterAndPublish", () -> new MyProcessor(), SOURCE_NAME)
```